# DB result Count in Group by results showing directly in Tableau

Tags: analytics, tableau-api

I am a newbie to Tableau, I am able to create graphs and analytics from raw data (required columns / fields queried with conditions).

But I feel instead of Tableau showing the count etc. by extracting the raw data, 
Is there a way  I can get count from DB directly grouped by other columns and represent it in Tableau.

E.g. suppose this is my DB table with **raw data**

```
COUNTRY USERTYPE    USERNAME    USERID
US  PREPAID u1  u1
US  PREPAID u2  u2
US  POSTPAID    u22 u22
IE  PREPAID u4  u4
IE  POSTPAID    u5  u5
.   .   .   .
.   .   .   .
.   .   .   .
```

and my count query is like

```
SELECT count(USERNAME), COUNTRY, USERTYPE
FROM USERSTABLE
WHERE USERNAME NOT NULL
GROUP BY COUNTRY, USERTYPE
```

**Data to tableau is (query I run in tableau)**

```
Country USERTYPE    COUNT
US  PREPAID 10
UK  PREPAID 20
IN  PREPAID 15
GB  PREPAID 8
IE  PREPAID 2
US  POSTPAID    9
UK  POSTPAID    5
IN  POSTPAID    3
GB  POSTPAID    6
IE  POSTPAID    65
```

I want to use the counts instead of raw data processing in tableau.

Appreciate any tips or way to do this.

**Why Am I doing this ?**

This is a very huge table with millions of rows, I do not want all of these to be pulled to tableau server, ther eis no other analytics done. Instead just get the count running query directly in DB Server

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom SQL query that only fetches the data you want from the server.

1. Open Tableau
2. Connect to your DB
3. Choose a DB
4. Under your list of tables you have a "New Custom SQL" option
5. Insert your query
6. Run

With that you only feed - in your case - the count of usergroup/country into Tableau and none of the RAW data.
If that's a one off thing, that's no problem. If you want to give it to your (non-technical) users you might want to create a view in the DB instead and connect to that from Tableau or extract that query to save on Tableau Server.